# RubyMine connect to database

Tags: postgresql, docker, rubymine

I'm using latest version of RubyMine and when I try to connect to my docker container database, I see the database, but not any of the tables etc.

If I use an external program such as Psequal using the exact same credentials, it works fine so I know I'm using the correct credentials, IP address etc.

I have raised [an issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000153990-Database-not-showing-tables) with JetBrains, but can anyone shed any light on why I'm not seeing the tables?

[image]

Comment: How have you tried to look at the tables? Try double clicking and/or clicking the refresh icon.

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of to refresh or expand further, but nothing

Comment: If you've tried to follow [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2017.1/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html) with no success you should raise an issue with JetBrains; if there's a bug in RubyMine that's not something SO can help with.

Comment: I have logged with JetBrains, but as is always the case, its somewhat difficult to judge whether its a bug or my error. Thats why I posted here to see if anyone knew

Comment: Could you at least link the issue, then?

Comment: Its the same thing I just posted above, execpt on the jetbrains support site

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000153990-Database-not-showing-tables

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. in the data source properties window (either when creating the data source or by right clicking->properties)

Go to options and tick the box "Introspect using JDBC meta data"

Click apply and you see a downloading progress bar

Once completed, the tables and everything else is viewable.